# why is PyCharm only running main.py even when im on another py file?

Tags: pycharm

So I use PyCharm to type code. So I found a little problem, when I opened a new file inside a directory and when I type code and run it, it just keeps grinning the code that I have in main.py other than the new file I have created. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The quickest way to run your current code is to righ-click inside it and then run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select what you want to run.

Right click on the tab of the selected file -> Run

or

in Project section, right click on file -> Run

or

inside it anywhere outside the code right click -> Run